# webpack performance questions - common with gulp cache, parallel build, loaders chain as stream representation

Tags: webpack

1) Main `gulp` feature is using nodejs streams for build acceleration.
Does `webpack` loaders chain works the same way?
`webpack-stream` `gulp` plugin is not an answer, IMHO, i.e. it simply launches `webpack` on entries.

2) Does `webpack` builds parallels without `webpack-parallel` or this plugin is necessary?

3) `gulp` cache, plugins (`gulp-newer`, `gulp-cached`, `gulp-remember`) and `webpack-dev-server` cache problem - how to create common cache?

Comment: Suggested reading http://blog.andrewray.me/webpack-when-to-use-and-why/

Comment: I have read this article before. There is not any actual info relatively discussion topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally there is no reason to use Gulp if you're using Webpack. Webpack manages all files, both static assets and source code, in your project. There may be special cases that require Gulp but I haven't run into them personally.

1. I don't fully understand what you're asking, apologies if I'm completely misinterpreting it: For development you should be running the webpack dev server in the background, which will keep your bundle up to date in real time. There's no benefit to calling webpack through gulp.
2. Webpack is fairly slow in general, and does not do anything in parallel by default. The [Happypack](https://github.com/amireh/happypack) project is a good solution to this problem and fairly easy to install.
3. Webpack rebuilds the entire "bundle" of code on change to any source file. If you want to cache things outside of the bundled file in development mode, use the [DLLPlugin](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/list-of-plugins#dllplugin), which builds a separate file to disk indepdendent of your runtime hot reloading development bundle.

Comment: Thank you for reply;

1) I also thought before that `webpack` completely replaces `gulp`, but there are several use cases where `gulp` can be useful - tasks manager (makefiles are harder to write, IMHO) and ability to write `webpack` config in es6/7 via babel (so, `gulp` is wrapper). But, ... yes, you are right, `gulp` is completely unnecessary.

2) Does `happypack` plays well with `webpack` loaders, plugins, etc?

3) Sounds interesting, but now I couldnt understand it's use cases.